# Intersection vs union in mapped type

Tags: typescript

Following up on my question [Force object properties to pick one interface key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936948/force-object-properties-to-pick-one-interface-key), I have now a problem when using the return value of one function as an argument to another function - though the types should be the same within the same key.

Consider this code:

```
interface ItemTypePerModule {
    module1: { foo1: string }
    module2: { foo2: string }
}

type ModuleMapping<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: {
        read: () => Promise<T[P]>
        update: (existingItem: T[P]) => Promise<void>
    }
}

const moduleReadAndUpdate: ModuleMapping<ItemTypePerModule> = {
    module1: {
        read: () => { return Promise.resolve( {foo1: "myItem"} ) },
        update: (existingItem) => {
            console.log(existingItem.foo1)
            return Promise.resolve()
        },
    },
    module2: {
        read: () => { return Promise.resolve( {foo2: "myItem"} ) },
        update: (existingItem) => {
            console.log(existingItem.foo2)
            return Promise.resolve()
        },
    }
}

async function doStuffInAllModules() {
    const modules = Object.keys(moduleReadAndUpdate) as Array<keyof ItemTypePerModule>
    for(const mod of modules) {
        const item = await moduleReadAndUpdate[mod].read()
        await moduleReadAndUpdate[mod].update(item)
    }
}
```

In the last code line (`await moduleReadAndUpdate[mod].update(item)`) I get the error

```
Argument of type '{ foo1: string; } | { foo2: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo1: string; } & { foo2: string; }'.
  Type '{ foo1: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo1: string; } & { foo2: string; }'.
    Property 'foo2' is missing in type '{ foo1: string; }' but required in type '{ foo2: string; }'.
```

Actually, within the same module the return value of `read` and the param for `update` should be typed the same. I.e. when I'm processing `module1` then the type is always `{ foo1: string }` and never `{ foo2: string }`.  However, according to the error message it seems TypeScript doesn't really "understand" and does some weird assumptions with unions and intersections instead.

So, I'm inclined to think that this might be a TypeScript limitation. But how can I work around it?

Comment: In TS4.6 you will be able to get the compiler to see the correlation (from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) if your code is generic in `K extends keyof ItemTypePerModule`, but the refactoring necessary to do this with promises in a loop is annoying. [This](https://tsplay.dev/mpg8pN) is the best I could do. I could write up an answer if you want, for completeness, although the easiest way for you to proceed is just to use a type assertion as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't correlate `mod` and `item` in this way, typescript just doesn't understand this pattern. You will need to use a type assertion:

```
async function doStuffInAllModules() {
    const modules = Object.keys(moduleReadAndUpdate) as Array<keyof ItemTypePerModule>
    for(const mod of modules) {
        const item = await moduleReadAndUpdate[mod].read()
        await moduleReadAndUpdate[mod].update(item as never)
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYBUCeAHCABWgFkB7AEwFcAbFAbwChkXkNLaIBGALmXuQwyZXsgDOYKKADmyAL7NW7anQBMfAULLrxkmfMYLGYfCnIqIJOHjwyAPFgB8yALz9FLANqFkoZAGsIHDIYZCwAXQ0PVhYoCDgKPgAKAEpXZ0IoMgxgMQgHb3DHaJiqPAo4SGSIAA9csBl0CAw+LEK0lwysnLy7ADcyYApimIUjBDIQCTYOOgAleIoAQRAKAFVyyog+c04rG3sm7FNiKF26ZzcmGOVOUWuY1jiE5I7nATiwKigQZEzs3IQAB0cTEZBofQgSX4WlEACIMDgjnC5Mg0nIADQlVhlCpVZBJWr1RqYN7uR4U5ATKbg4E0MjSQl1CQk5pA2EpbEUz7fX7-HrA0HgyGpLnyLGjCVKWYQHQPbmLV7pfjIHk-P7dQEgiBgiFQmHCHQIpGYFFo8Vi3FbarMhogaRHMnyyksam6ukMpnE+1HdmGzkumJqvmavLa3UigOUzHRMaMRhwMQ4EAIQRUFMNSbIChkADKXxgMFQICWNBo5x1qXJrDdYBmFjErmQAHkAEYAKwgCDAQMCODESVu80WK3Wm0gaUTyCWUCgcBwdj7ITQmFwBFOFZGrCEUCStfryGXQ51aWdMX3wEwTbgAHc4Jf65wFglRxs8RBPMpwtqEqKXbf7zrY9n2WVY3y2T9KG-K1ICSS9mmQKcQAgSEoCjFgxiAA)

Comment: OK, thanks. But why assert as `never`? I think `any` would make more sense.

Comment: @cis Either works. `never` is the subtype of any other type to it will be assignable to the intersection.